# Using Arrays as Method (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I am having problems getting my class to compile. It is giving me errors such as "double cannot be dereferenced" and "cannot find symbol".

The diver is:

```
 public class MinilabArraysDriver{
    public static void main(String[ ] args){
       //create a 1d array of ints
       int[ ] array1d = { 8, 8, 7, 5, 3 };

       //call mean1d Method to find the mean (note the static call...)
       double theMean = MinilabArrays.mean1d(array1d);

       //print the original array and the mean
       System.out.print("The mean of: { ");
        for (int i=0; i<array1d.length; i++){
              if (i != 0)
                  System.out.print("   ");
             //print first for separation (except before first element)
             System.out.print(array1d[i]);
         }
        System.out.print(" }   is:  " + theMean);
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        //create a 2d array of doubles
        double[ ][ ] array2d =  {{ 3.4,  5.1,  8.0},
                                 { 5.23,  8.2 },
                                 { 10.7 },
                                 { 2.9 }
                                };
        //call sum2d to get the sum
        double total = MinilabArrays.sum2d(array2d);

        //print the 2D array
        for (int row=0; row<array2d.length; row++){
             System.out.println();
             for (int col=0; col<array2d[row].length; col++)
                  System.out.print(array2d[row][col] + "\t");
            }
        //print the result
        System.out.println("\n\nTotal of 2d array is: " + total);
        System.out.println("\n\n");
       }
}
```

And here is the class that I am trying to write:

```
public class MinilabArrays{
  public static double mean1d(int[ ] theMean){
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ;i < theMean.length ; i++){
            total = total + theMean [ i ];
            total = total / theMean.length;
            return total;
        }
    }

   public static double sum2d(double [ ] theSum){
    double total2, total3, total4 = 0;
    for(int row=0 ; row < theSum.length ; row++){
        for (int col=0 ; col<theSum[row].length ; col++)
            total2 = total2 + theSum[col];
        }
    total3 = total3 + theSum[row];
    total4 = total3 + total2;
    return total4;
   }
}
```

For "mean1d" I am trying to find the mean or average of the given number, and for "sum2d" I am trying to find the total of the given number.

Sorry if my code is stupid or dumb. I cannot check it if it won't let me compile.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting?

Comment: When you do get it to compile, you're going to find that the loop in `mean1d` isn't really a loop.  It will execute only once and then leave.

Comment: I am getting "double cannot be dereferenced" and "cannot find symbol."

Comment: You have a bunch of errors in your code, both syntax and logically. I would recommend using an IDE like Eclipse to help you debug.

Comment: Issues I see with a quick glance: `mean1d()` is returning inside the loop, `sum2d()` has the wrong argument type based on what you pass in, `total2` and `total3` need to be initialized, `row` needs to be declared outside your loop, `double` types don't have length properties....

Comment: Should I use Eclipses or NetBeans? Currently, I am doing this on TextPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling sum2d method by passing 2D array in parameter and declared this method as a 1D array as parameter.

MinilabArrays.java

```
public static double sum2d(double[][] theSum) {
    double total2 = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < theSum.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < theSum[row].length; col++){
            total2 = total2 + theSum[row][col];
        }
    }
    return total2;
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help everyone. Object oriented programming is very difficult for me to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 1):

The first error comes from this line `for (int col=0 ; col<theSum[row].length ; col++)`. You are using a two-dimensional array `theSum[][]` but declared a one-dimensional array as method parameter.

The other error comes from the use of `row` outside of its scope. You declared it inside this for-loop `for(int row=0 ; row < theSum.length ; row++)` but used it outside of the for-loop.

Comment: How do I fix it? The number in the array itself is a double but the col and row are int.

Comment: @Paincakes The comparison is simply not possible. You have to re-think what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

**MinilabArrays.sum2d(array2d)** requires a *double[]* not the *double[][]* here. 
And also at this point **total3 = total3 + theSum[row];** cannot access the variable **row** outside of the for loop.

Comment: I just put "total3 = total3 + theSum[row];" inside the for loop.                                                  {
   for (int col=0 ; col<theSum[row].length ; col++)
    total2 = total2 + theSum[col];
    total3 = total3 + theSum[row];
  }